# Save Responses to a file Listerner - Setting file name

Tags: jmeter

I've a JMeter test plan with a number of HTTPRequests. For each HTTPRequest I have added a "Save Responses to a file" Listener when a failure occurs. Ideally I would like the file name to be the same as the label of the Request it is logging it for with a suffix "_FAILURE" added.

Is there any way of using a single "Save Responses to a file" Listener at the top level of my plan and having this be generated automatically rather than having to set manually myself for each?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any listener has access to SampleResult of sampler that was run last. You can get it using [__Beanshell](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__BeanShell) function. SampleResult has [method for getting sampler label](http://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#getSampleLabel%28%29). So filename prefix of Save Responses to File listener will be:

```
${__BeanShell(SampleResult.getSampleLabel())}_FAILURE
```